# Auto-click button in div on-load

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page where I modded an app to prepopulate a number of fields. I would like to automatically have the 'submit' button be pressed/submitted when the page loads. I have tried things like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function autoclick() {
        document.getElementById('buttonid').click();
}
</script>
```

with

```
<body onload="autoclick()">
```

But it does not work.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

(It is the iframe on this site: http://abraxas.pw)

Comment: so what's your problem here?

Comment: It doesn't automatically click the div?

Comment: It should i guess,if you're not doing wrong at other places.

Comment: well why you mentioned iframe here?Are you trying to fetch content in iframe  from your page?

Comment: Why would you attempt to click the button on page load. Rather, run the code that will be fired on button click.

Comment: If I knew how to do that/find it, i would. but I don't ;( (irc.abraxas.pw if you think you might be able to find it?)

Comment: if you don't care about using jQuery you can use instead of `onload="autoclick()"`:
the `$(document).ready(function{autoclick();});`
inside the iframe of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that your iframe is in the same domain and hence it will possible for you as the cross-domain security may not apply.

Give your `iframe` an `id`. And then:

```
document.getElementById('iframeName').contentWindow.document.getElementById("buttonid").click()
```

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting

Make sure that the DOM is fully loaded before you fire your Javascript. Wrap this code into `body` load or `iframe` load.

### Update:

If the iframe is in the same domain and is in your control, you don't need to do all this. Just fire the click from `domloaded` of jQuery, or place your code at the end (just before body ends). It will work.

Seeing your code, you have defined the function in the `head` and are calling it at `body` load. Place the function and the call at the end of the body.

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help, I'm still having some #newatcoding problems but I have this at the end of the html in the body of the iframe and it is still not working. I also tried putting the function earlier and the 'onload' on a separate element:

<script type="text/javascript" onload="autoclick()">
function autoclick() {
        document.getElementById('buttonid').click();
}
</script>

Comment: @Abraxas: It seems that your function is being called, but all required resources have not yet been loaded. You are loading resources async thru AJAX and hence the button click won't do anything whether you put it at the end or on page load. You will have to put that as a **last** call in your network call stack. i.e. identify when is your last AJAX call returning and then call the button click from there.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it in iframe for security reasons: http://pipwerks.com/2008/11/30/iframes-and-cross-domain-security-part-2/

Comment: I actually am hosting the iframe from another one of my servers. I have access to all of the code in the iframe. (see: irc.abraxas.pw)

Comment: I had a look at that iframe. There is no communication between the parent page and the iframe; the "autoclick" function is defined inside the iframe header tag. Btw, is the function called? Try to log something to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Content coming from different domain in iframe  can't be controlled in your page using javascript.
Browser treats iframe as a different window so you've no access over it. it's something like trying to access content of different window open in your browser from your own window(which is obviously not possible)