# Auto click div in webview in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

In an iframe, you can do this:

[Auto-click button in div on-load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954685/auto-click-button-in-div-on-load)

Is it possible to do this within a Chrome App Webview? And cross domains?

Comment: Did you read the docs? https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-executeScript

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas where I would put this code within the Chrome App framework?